# how can i call a web API and assign he returned JSON to hidden fields

Tags: java, json

I have a web API `(/WcfJson/Service1.svc/VF/GetDocInfo)` that returned the following JSON values:-

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      " Ser": 1,
      " No": 1
    },
    {
      " Ser": 2,
      " No": 2
    },
    {
      " Ser": 3,
      " No": 3
    },
    {
      " Ser": 4,
      " No": 4
    },
    {
      " Ser": 5,
      " No": 5
    },
    {
      " Ser": 6,
      " No": 6
    },
    {
      " Ser": 7,
      " No": 7
    },
    {
      " Ser": 8,
      " No": 8
    }
  ]
}
```

and i need to store the values of the returned JSON on my form hidden values, i can access the form hidden values by the following expression #formName.fieldName#.
So how can i write a standard Java class that do the following:-

1-Call the web API.

2-Handle the returned JSON.

3-Assign the returned JOSN  to the hidden fields.

Best Regards

Comment: Do you really need to handle this on the server?  A simple ajax call from the browser would prevent a trip to the server and most likely be easier to handle.

Comment: #formName.fieldName# is not a valid Java expression. What is the form you're talking about? Is it an HTML form? Are you confusing Java and JavaScript? Which value of the JSON object should go to which hidden field?

Comment: will on a real case the web API call will contain a user name and password, so i can not expose them to the users, that why i need to do it on the server.

Comment: i am working on a BPM and it enable to access the html form values using the following expression #formName.fieldName#